# Regex to replace 'title' but not 'post_title'

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I want to replace 'title' words to 'post_title' but ignore the 'post_title' words which already exist, so it do not become 'post_post_title', or any 'someword_title'.
Just 'title'. Period.

I've tried with:

```
/[a-z_]?title/i
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Try `/(?<!_)title/i` or just `/\btitle\b/i` (to replace `title` as a whole word).

Comment: Whoa.. that was quick. Yeah, you're right. Great thanks!!